# PHP file_put_contents or fwrite ' and " characters

Tags: php, file-io

Hey guys,
how do I write " and ' characters when I'm doing it via PHP
eg

```
<?php
$newFile = "<?php echo 'quote: "hello world"'; ?>"
file_put_contents('index.php', $newFile);
 ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\` is used to 'escape' things.

```
$newfile = "<?php echo 'quote: \"hello world\"'; ?>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only use one sort of quotes in a string literal. If another quote is to appear within the literal it needs to be escaped by a `\`

```
$newFile = "<?php echo 'quote: \"hello world\"'; ?>";
file_put_contents('index.php', $newFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newFile = "<?php echo 'quote: \"hello world\"'; ?>"
```

Read this [Strings manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).